# How can I make a border appear on top of it's content in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf

I made a Border around a ScrollViewer and a TextBlock, but their corners are slighty extending over my border's round corners. How can I make it go the other way around?
I tried using Panel.ZIndex but it didn't work.
Here's my code:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Behaviors="clr-namespace:UI.Behaviors;assembly=UI.Behaviors"
    Title="My app" Height="408" Width="523" Closed="Window_Closed" Visibility="Visible"
    Behaviors:FocusBehavior.FocusFirst="True" Closing="Window_Closing">
    <Grid>
        <Border
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Panel.ZIndex="3"
            BorderThickness="4"
            CornerRadius="10"
            BorderBrush="Black" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="12,50,8,48">
                <ScrollViewer Panel.ZIndex="2" Name="ScrollViewer1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ClipToBounds="True" >
                    <TextBlock Background="WhiteSmoke" Panel.ZIndex="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your border a padding (e.g. "5") and set its background to the same as your TextBlock (i.e. "WhiteSmoke").